Extracting audio from video using fluent-ffmpeg
Im trying to extract the audio from a video, an error is occuring
Error converting file: Error: ffmpeg exited with code 234: Error opening output file ./src/videos/output-audio.mp3.
Error opening output files: Invalid argument
I use this same directory for my video compression that runs before this one and it works.
ffmpeg()
  .input(url)
  .audioChannels(0)
  .format("mp3")
  .output("./src/videos/output-audio.mp3")
  .on("error", (err) => console.error(`Error converting file: ${err}`))
  .on("end", async () => {
    console.log("audio transcripts");
   
    const stream = fs.createReadStream("./src/videos/output-audio.mp3");
    const transcription = await openai.audio.transcriptions.create({
      file: stream,
      model: "whisper-1",
      response_format: "verbose_json",
      timestamp_granularities: ["word"],
    });
    transcripts = transcription.text;
    console.log(transcription.text);
  })
  .run();

